# Windows batch command for file copy

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

Currently I am working with an old vbs script. In that I found that it calls an another .bat file.

```
WshShell.run "abc.bat " + logfilename + " " + exlogfilename ,3, True
```

The abc.bat file contains below code.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "skip=1 delims=*" %%a IN ('dir /O-D /B \\server1\xyz\*.log') 
DO move \\server1\xyz\%%a D:\folder1\
```

Could anyone please explain what these two lines will exactly do. I've basic idea but confused with the parameters.
Powershell alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: It appears to be moving all log files, except for the most recent, from the `xyz` directory to `D:\folder1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it moves (not copies) every logfile (extension *.log) from the server `\\server1`, subdirectory `\\server1\xyz` to a local directory `D:\Folder1`.

The directives `/O-D` and `/B` are just there to make the script work (ordering the results and showing only filenames). They don't modify the behaviour of the batchfile.

Comment: _"The directives /O-D and /B are just there to make the script work. They don't modify the behaviour of the batchfile."_ I am sorry, but that is completely wrong. `/O` is a sort order switch using `-D` which is sorting by date in reverse order. `/B` is a bare format switch. All of these switches modify the behaviour of the outcome of the batch script.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: indeed, I just meant that those switches don't cause the `dir` command to start searching subdirectories or things like that.

Comment: Maybe just add what the switches does then

Comment: Could you please tell me what these parameters means
 /F "skip=1 delims=*"

Comment: @user10644895 open cmd.exe and type `for /?` it will give you everything you need to know about the for loop.